# Difference between "disharmonisch" and "unharmonisch"

Tags: antonym

So I came upon an exercise where I needed to find word's antonyms and found that "disharmonisch" and "unharmonisch" were both valid for harmonisch. Are they really identical or is there a slight difference?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

*[Unharmonisch](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/unharmonisch)* has two meanings according to Duden:

> 1. something is not harmonic
> 2. something, e.g. colors/ forms, does not match

[Disharmonisch](http://www.duden.de/rechtschreibung/disharmonisch) has four meanings according to Duden:

> 1. tones does not sound good together; music has a dissonance
> 2. something, e.g. colors/ forms, does not match
> 3. being in a state of disharmony
> 4. (Geology; Folding of rockt) differently shaped

So, *unharmonisch* and *disharmonisch* are interchangeable in their meaning that something, e.g. colors/ forms, does not match. And even though the "something" could be music, *disharmonisch* is here the better choice. In the geological setting you can only use *disharmonisch*.

In addition, I would say that *disharmonisch* generally is stronger that *unharmonisch*. When I think about the combination of different colors, *unharmonisch* is a slight disturbance for me, but *disharmisch* is a really strong (negative) contrast.

Answer (score 3):

I'd say that there is a slight difference.

"Disharmonisch"  might be translated as "anti-harmonic," or having *bad* harmony.

The sense of "unharmonisch" is more like "not harmonic." That is, "not good," certainly, but not necessarily bad.

Answer (score 1):

Where they are interchangeable, which they often are, they do mean exactly the same.

However:

- there can be a `Disharmonie` (in any context where either makes sense) but I  `Unharmonie` is not a word at all.
- for music and most other scientific contexts, I would prefer `disharmonisch`.
- people on the other hand are always `unharmonisch` (with each other), never `disharmonisch`.